# Facebook IOS sdk after login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

i've got a Facebook login in my IOS application.
is possible after login to show another view controller?

here is the code in ViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "dashBoardViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()



@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueToDestinationViewController" sender:self];
}


-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{


}


-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


@end
```

i tried some code and answer from web, but after i login it shows me the same page with the blue Facebook button "Log Out" i only need to go in another View and passing the FacebookID and the Facebook Username. is that possible?
where's the error?

**EDIT**
i changed my method to this :

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and in my ViewController.h i added :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ViewController *dashBoardViewController;
```

it says me to change

```
   [self.navigationController presentViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

TO

```
   [self.navigationController presentViewController:_dashBoardViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when i do that it's the same result

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YourViewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:YourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: `loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user` method. create first `YourViewController`

Comment: does your `dashBoardViewController` has `Storyboard ID`? my advice is to add an ID to that view controller then create the it as: `DashBoardViewController *dbVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIDhere"];` then `[self.navigationController presentViewController:dbVC animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: i set the ID (dashboard) where i've to put the `DashBoardViewController *dbVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIDhere"];` in my `loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user` method but it says me  'use of undeclared identifier dbvc' @dizzyboy

Comment: add that now inside that method
[self.navigationController presentViewController:dbVC animated:YES completion:nil];